# PHP contact form script won't run/ page opens instead

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm stuck and I hope someone can help me. I'm trying to add a simple contact form to my website using PHP action=" " method="post". When I click the "submit" button, instead of running the script, the "send_contact.php" page opens and you see all the code. I've checked and tested my server (blue.host) and it is set up to run php scripts. I've tried everything and I'm at a loss. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form">
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="send_contact.php" method="post">
<label>Name</label>

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />                 
<label>E-mail</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

<label>Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />

<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>

<button name="send" type="submit">send</button>
<button name="reset" type="reset">reset</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</form><!--end myform div-->
</div><!--end form div-->
```

Here's the PHP script:

```
<?php

// From
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail";

// Contact phone
$phone ="$phone"; 

// Details
$message="$message";


// Enter your email address
$to ='jacine.arias@gmail.com';

$send_contact=mail($to,$header,$mail,$phone,$message);


// Check, if message sent to your email
// display message "Thank you! Your message has been recieved."
if($send_contact){
echo "Thank you! Your message has been recieved.";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/*-----------FORM---------------*/

.form {
    border: 1px solid #262223;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 375px;

}

.form label {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
}

.form input {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #262223;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 2px 0 10px 10px;
}

textarea {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #262223;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 31px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #F20F4B;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

button[type="reset"] {
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 31px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #F20F4B;
    display: inline;
}
```

Here the actual page from my website:http://jacineariasdesign.jacineariasweb.com/contact.html
Any help to make this work would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Just to make sure php **is** running and working try putting phpinfo(); in a php file and opening it in your browser.

Comment: For one thing, running your URL, your entire script is `commented`. E.g. `// From $header="from: $name <$mail_from>";` So, of course it won't work. Remove all `//`.

Comment: See this article from your host: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/128

Comment: @Fred, not it isn't it just doesn't have any HTML breaks in it so it appears like that. view the source.

Comment: Just double check that you're including `<?php` at the top as this isn't being printed.

Comment: `To ALL` in thread: There are no `$_POST`s. Wouldn't that cause this, what are you views on this? For example `$mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];` etc.

Comment: @Fred - That would cause an error but I can't imagine it would force the whole script to be printed. The OP should really try a simple file with `<?php echo '1'; ?>` or something basic just to see whether it's the script or his server.

Comment: Found an error, many actually but this one is mandatory. There is no `subject` set anywhere. I suggest you totally re-write your mailer script. Format is `send to`, then `the subject`, then `the message`, then `your headers`.

Comment: `Added note` > FYI: Your `$customer_mail` doesn't reflect your form `email` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here, give this a try.** Tested and could stand to be modified with extra security features, **but it works** with your form supplied.

Added a bit of error checking also.

**If it doesn't work for you, then you have a PHP issue on "your" server.**

Your original PHP script never had a `Subject` entry to start with.

```
<?php

$headersep = "\r\n";
$header = "From: $name <$email>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: $name <$email> . $headersep";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject="Your subject here";
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$message = "From: $name\n\nMessage: $message\n\nEmail: $email\n\nTelephone: $phone";
$to ='youremail@example.com';

if (!empty ($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['message'])) {
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
echo "Thank you $name, your message has been received.";
exit;
}

if ( (empty ($_POST['email'])) && (empty ($_POST['message'])) ) {
echo "ERROR, you did not fill in the <b>Email</b> and the <b>message</b> body.";
exit;
}

elseif (empty ($_POST['email'])) {
echo "ERROR, you did not fill in your Email address.";
exit;
}

elseif (empty ($_POST['message'])) {
echo "ERROR, you did not fill in the message body.";
exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I changed the <button> attribute to <input> and then I changed the PHP to something similar to what Fred suggested and it worked! I appreciate all of the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your site, and see that your file does end in .php.  I think that your server has not been set up to execute .php files as php.

You'll have to work with the administrator of your server to make sure that .php files are being run through the php handler.

The specifics of the configuration are going to depend on your server platform ... There are a lot of sites out there to walk you through the steps.  I don't want to recommend one specifically because I don't know what your starting point is.

Answer (score 0):

please see my php script below. I have set up SSMTP and `echo "hello " | mail -s "test" mail@gmail.com` from Ubuntu command line sends mail.

```
<?php
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Contact form <www.sabinamortgages.ca>';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'Sabina <sabina.kandik@premieremortgage.ca>';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'need' => 'Need', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); 

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

/*
 *  LET'S DO THE SENDING
 */


// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: Looking for any help that I can get I'm just very stuck and very new to this