# Index.php opens instead of Sending the Message

Tags: php, html, web, submit

I have searched 
[PHP contact form script won't run/ page opens instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197720/php-contact-form-script-wont-run-page-opens-instead#)

[click submit in html and run php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177052/click-submit-in-html-and-run-php-code)

But couldnt get an answer - it did not work.

As the header suggests : I am trying to submit information displayed on a web page to an email address listed.

Here is the send message part of my html :

```
<form method="post" action="contactform/index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input name="fname" placeholder="Type Here">
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input name="surname" placeholder="Type Here">
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>ID Number (For Voting)</label>
        <input name="idnumb" placeholder="Type Here">
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input name="addr" placeholder="Type Here">
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
        <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
    <div class="text-center"><button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

This is a code snippet at the bottom of the page.

There is a contactform.js for validation. Then there is the php file index.php located in a folder on the server called contactform:

```
<?php
    $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $idnumb = $_POST['idnumb'];
    $address = $_POST['addr'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Test'; 
    $to = 'avahed87@gmail.com'; 
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "Registration from $firstname $surname\n ID:$idnumb\n  Email : $email\n Address : $address\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
?>
```

Basically I need to send this info the email address attached. I am fairly new to web development so any advice or reference to a tutorial would be helpful.

I mimiced the code from [this article](http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/)

Comment: Please tell us what happens when you run your code, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Do you mean the PHP is not parsing? Have you actually installed PHP?

Comment: It sounds like PHP is not installed on the server your code is running on.  If you see the PHP code itself as plain text, that is the case.

Comment: Are you coding this locally on your machine? You're going to need a local server to run PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed `php` and it is running fine for remaining php files then I guess your problem will be  this:

When validation is correct and after submission it will automatically go to the php file specified in **action** attribute.

There php file will remain open until and unless you used **header** to go to another file. And one thing I noticed here is your code may get an error if you directly open `index.php` file because while opening directly there won't be any `$_POST['variables']`. So it is better to use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])`

Then use remaining variables.